# How to disable button click until item selected/activated?

Tags: angularjs

Trying to disable button in table. and enable it only when item selected/clicked/activated

button code

```
<td><a class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="isDisabled">Edit</a></td>
```

disabled bool
    `$scope.isDisabled = false;`

trying to enable button only when selected is true

```
$scope.selectedRow = false; // initialize our variable to null
$scope.setClickedRow = function(index) { //function that sets the value of selectedRow to current index
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
    $scope.isDisabled = true;
}
```

any help please?
http://plnkr.co/edit/llmcbXCA93kuTVTzpQlm?p=catalogue

the full table

```
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="hidden-xs">ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr> 
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                      <tr ng-repeat="trainee in trainees | filter: search" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
                        <td class="hidden-xs">{{$index+1}}</td>
                        <td>{{trainee.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{trainee.date | date:'d/M/yyyy'}}</td>
                        <td>{{trainee.grade}}</td>
                        <td>{{trainee.subject}}</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-info">Edit</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: show the full table

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/llmcbXCA93kuTVTzpQlm?p=catalogue

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/c7UC9mfdJIMHF8ctq5ft?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First make the plunk work!**

You were referencing a file that didn't exist in the plunk, so had to change:

`<script src="main.js"></script>` to `<script src="script.js"></script>`.

**Amend your `ng-disabled` directive:**

Also had to add `ng-disabled="selectedRow !== $index"` on your link button:

```
<td><a class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="selectedRow !== $index">Edit</a></td>
```

I don't think you need the `$scope.disabled` variable as the `$scope.selectedRow` along with `$index` takes care of enabling/disabling each edit button.

**Prevent click events from bubbling up the DOM tree:**

The `ng-click` on your `tr` tag will be triggered by any `ng-click` that you place on your edit link button, to fix that you have to add `$event.stopPropagation();` after any function that you put there:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" 
   ng-disabled="selectedRow === $index" 
   ng-click="onEditButtonClicked(); $event.stopPropagation();">
 Edit
</a>
```

**Fix Invalid HTML Markup:**

Moved the following up and out of the table:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
    <a type="button" href="#add-form" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addForm()">Add new trainee</a>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeTrainee(trainee)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

**Styles.css 404 not Found:**

Last but not least `styles.css` doesn't exist and gets a 404 not found, and so the following can be removed: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

[**Working Plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/c7UC9mfdJIMHF8ctq5ft?p=preview)

Comment: wow matthew. thank you so mach. didnt know that ng-click can handle two conditians. and sorry for broken plnkr.